# Dropdown list arrow is not working after showing the required field error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying some list of ids as follows

```
<li>
<label> Nest</label>
<select id="NestId" class="Select input-validation-error" name="NestId" data-val-required="Please select nest name." data-val-number="The field Nest ipId must be a number." data-val="true">
<span data-valmsg-for="NestId"></span>
<div class="formError NestshipId" style="top: -69px; left: 202px; opacity: 0.8;">
</li>
```

The arrow of the ddl is working fine before showing the requirefield erorr msg.Once its shown, some part of it is shadowig over the ddl arrow.
so the arrow is not clickable through the erorr message

When I inspect the code through firebug, I could see the element like this

```
<li>
<label> Relation</label>
<select id="NestId" class="Select input-validation-error"     name="NestId" data-val-required="Please select relation." data-val-  number="The field NestId must be a number." data-val="true">
<span data-valmsg-for="NestId"></span>
<div class="formError NestId" style="top: -69px; left: 202px; opacity: 0.8;">
```

```
.input-validation-error
{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
background-color: #ffeeee;
}

<div class="formError NestId" style="top: -69px; left: 202px; opacity: 0.8;">
<div class="formErrorContent">Please select relation.</div>
</div>
```

I think the arrow is not clickable because of the presence of field message over it.
Can anybody please help me to find a solution for this.
The message should be visible as well as the ddl arrow should work

Comment: I don't think you need to provide `[Required]` attribute for dropdownlist, as it always holds some value even the user didn't change the options. Try removing the `[Required]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting the position of the error message to the left, in this case it will not be overlapping on the dropdown arrow.

```
.input-validation-error
{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
background-color: #ffeeee;
position:relative;
left:20px;
}
```

Comment: HI,This is the css for the required field error message.           .formError .formErrorContent
    {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ee0101;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    display:inline; 
    }

Comment: where is the position specification in this?

Comment: Can you modify it and give to me?